# Is there any way to change text color of igx-grid-cell based on text

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, infragistics, ignite-ui

I am using ignite ui for the first time in angular. I am facing some problem. Basically I have created library for ignite ui grid and consuming it. I want to make particular grid cell text color change based on text which i am passing in my grid columns like this( in 2nd object using property `textColorChange` and `textColor`)

```
{
            field: 'ProductName',
            resizable: true,
            sortable: true,
            filterable: true,
            isTooltip: true,
            isHtml: true,
         },
         {
            field: 'QuantityPerUnit',
            filterable: true,
            sortable: true,
            columnWidth: '200px',
            textColorChange: true,
            textColor: [{text: 'Success', color: 'green'},{text: 'Failure', color: 'red'}]
         },
```

above object states that in column `QuantityPerUnit` if I found `Success` keyword then change the text color to green, same for `Failure` keyword also or any keyword.

This is I tried:

> html

```
  <igx-column
         #col
         *ngFor="let column of columns"
         [field]="column.field"
         [header]="column.title ? column.title : column.field"
         [dataType]="column.dataType ? column.dataType : 'string'"
         width="{{ column.columnWidth ? column.columnWidth : config.defaultColumnWidth }}"
         [cellClasses]="column.textColorChange ? textColorChangeClasses: ''"
      >
```

> ts

```
private successTextColorCondition(rowData: any, columnKey: any): boolean {
    return rowData[columnKey] === this.columns.forEach((text) => {
      text.textColor['text']
    })
  }
  private failureTextColorCondition(rowData: any, columnKey: any): boolean{
    return rowData[columnKey] === 'Failure'
  }
  textColorChangeClasses = {
    successText: this.successTextColorCondition
  };
```

.scss

```
.successText {
   color: $success-text-color
}
```

But I am getting error `core.js:4352 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'columns' of undefined`

Is this correct way to do it? or is there any other way to achieve this.

I took help of this stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/github/IgniteUI/igniteui-live-editing-samples/tree/master/angular-demos/grid/grid-cell-styling

Answer (score 1):

[`cellClasses`](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/docs/typescript/latest/classes/igxcolumncomponent.html#cellclasses) accepts object literal, containing key-value pairs. Key is the name of the CSS class, while the value is either a callback function that returns a boolean, or boolean. Note the third parameter - it is the cell value. In your case if it is `success` you should return `true`, should not you?

What you are doing in `successTextColorCondition` is:

```
private successTextColorCondition(rowData: any, columnKey: any): boolean {
    return rowData[columnKey] === this.columns.forEach((text) => {
        text.textColor['text']
    })
}
```

`this.columns.forEach` will always return `undefined`, and the class will never be applied.

Actually once you reach the `successTextColorCondition` you are sure `textColorChange` is `true` for this column, and you have `rowData`, `columnKey`, `cellValue` and `rowIndex` provided as parameters. What you can do is check depending on the cell value if the cell is successful or not. Something like this:

```
private downFontCondition = (rowData: any, columnKey: any, cellValue): boolean => {
    return cellValue === 'Success'; // you may change condition here
}
```

Also looking at code you provided I do not see a reason to provide `textColor` in your column object.